# Converting a variable containing the number of months to X Years, X.5 Months format?

Tags: php, date, time, intervals

I have use the following code to achieve this:

```
$total_months = 59;
$years  = (int)($total_months / 12);
$months = $total_months % 12;
```

The output is 4 years, 11 months ...

If input is:

```
$total_months = 59.5; 
$years  = (int)($total_months / 12);
$months = $total_months % 12;
```

I need the output as 4 years , 11.5 months ...

Would someone help me out to get the result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$months = $total_months - ($years * 12);`?

Comment: For years you could beter do floor($total_months / 12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u can use this:

```
$months = fmod($total_months, 12);
```

Comment: +1 Best solution for this, this function exactly matches the given requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_months = 59.5; 

$sub_month=$total_months - floor($total_months);
$years  = (int)($total_months / 12);
$months = $total_months % 12;

$months=$months+$sub_month;
```